# How to search id from one table in another table's nvarchar column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query, like

I have 2 tables

```
table1 ( id int, name nvarchar)
table2 ( pid int, parameters nvarchar)
```

parameters in table2 contains table1.id in nvarchar format, like 
"some text 12345 some text", where 12345 is the id which is contained in table1.
Now I need to find all the table1.id s which are mentionioned in table2.parameters

So for my script is this, but this does not work

```
select id, name 
from table1 r
where exists
(
select [Parameters] from table2
where [Parameters] like cast(r.id as nvarchar(15))
)
```

I can't use % with like but I need it. What is the way I can do it?

Comment: Don't use this schema to store parameters (with free text), use a proper table with `ParameterID, Value` so you don't have this parsing nightmares.You will need to find a pattern that can match on your strings so you can subtract your ID from the 2nd table. The pattern or the expression will greatly depend on the values you have so include as many representative examples as you have.

Comment: *I can't use % with like* `WHERE CHARINDEX(CAST(table1.id AS VARCHAR), table2.parameters) > 0`

Comment: Why can't you use % with like?  You can try splitting the spaces using STRING_SPLIT() if the parameters are always separated with spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your support, it really helped!

Comment: But how to implement the charindex() function if I cannot join table1 and table2? @Akina Can I use a subquery in charindex()? It gives an error when I try

Comment: *how to implement the charindex() function* T-SQL knows about it. [CHARINDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). *I cannot join table1 and table2* T-SQL knows about JOIN too... why you cannot? anycase correlated subquery usage is possible, even though it's not optimal.

Comment: I cannot join because they do not have common column, and when using Subquery in charindex() I get an error that there are multiple returns @Akina I try something like this

Comment: select charindex((select id from table1), [Parameters]) 
from table2

Comment: *they do not have common column* O_O `FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON CHARINDEX(CAST(table1.id AS VARCHAR), table2.parameters) > 0`... or `FROM table1, table2 WHERE CHARINDEX(CAST(table1.id AS VARCHAR), table2.parameters) > 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `%` with `LIKE`. Since you are converting the `INT` "id" into a string, you can then concatenate the `%` character on both sides. But you also need to include a space separating each of them from the converted "id" so that you don't have an "id" of 23 matching a `parameters` value of something like "abc 1234 def". And yes, you can `JOIN` the tables since that is just a different way of expressing the same thing that you are already attempting.

**SETUP**

```
-- DROP TABLE #table1;
CREATE TABLE #table1 ( [id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, [name] NVARCHAR(30));
-- DROP TABLE #table2;
CREATE TABLE #table2 ( [pid] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, [parameters] NVARCHAR(500));

SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO #table1 ([id], [name]) VALUES (1, N'a');
INSERT INTO #table1 ([id], [name]) VALUES (2, N'b');
INSERT INTO #table1 ([id], [name]) VALUES (3, N'c');
INSERT INTO #table1 ([id], [name]) VALUES (12, N'ab');
INSERT INTO #table1 ([id], [name]) VALUES (23, N'bc');
INSERT INTO #table1 ([id], [name]) VALUES (123, N'abc');


INSERT INTO #table2 ([pid], [parameters]) VALUES (1, N'some text 12345 some text');
INSERT INTO #table2 ([pid], [parameters]) VALUES (2, N'DD 2 DD');
INSERT INTO #table2 ([pid], [parameters]) VALUES (3, N'EEE EE 123 EEEEE');
INSERT INTO #table2 ([pid], [parameters]) VALUES (4, N'NO23 12NO');
INSERT INTO #table2 ([pid], [parameters]) VALUES (5, N'HHHHHH YYY 23 ZZZZZ');
INSERT INTO #table2 ([pid], [parameters]) VALUES (6, N'QQQQQ r2q RRRRR');
```

**CORRELATED SUBQUERY**

```
SELECT r.[id], r.[name]
FROM #table1 r
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM #table2 tmp
  WHERE tmp.[parameters] LIKE N'% ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), r.[id]) + N' %'
);
/*
id     name
2      b
23     bc
123    abc
*/
```

**JOIN**

```
SELECT t1.[id], t1.[name], t2.[pid]
FROM #table1 t1
INNER JOIN #table2 t2
        ON t2.[parameters] LIKE N'% ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(15), t1.[id]) + N' %';
/*
id     name    pid
2      b       2
23     bc      5
123    abc     3
*/
```